# How to make a grouping datatable with selection in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've tried with primefaces showcase examples, but I don't know how to make a grouping datatable with checkbox selection like this:
[image]

I've tried with `subtable`, `p:column` and `p:row`, but still I don't have an idea how to get same results such as if I use panelGrid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check multiple rows with one checkbox in the 'grouped' column, that is not supported in PrimeFaces up to the 6.3-SNAPSHOT. If it is/will be supported in future releases depends on an issue being created and it getting enough support or sponsor this via paid consultancy.

[Row grouping](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowGroup.xhtml) is what comes closest

```
<h3>Rowspan</h3>
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtRowGroupView.cars}" sortBy="#{car.brand}">
        <p:column headerText="Brand" groupRow="true">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

But I've not seen this work with selection or an additional 2nd grouped row

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this table was to compare the different values of each field to decide if the assumed `id` and `name` are taken as good. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

I used `ui:repeat`, `p:row` and `p:column` to get this customized table:

```
<h:form id="stocktakingTable">
<h:panelGroup layout="block" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <p:panelGrid>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>Ok</p:column>
                        <p:column>Assumed id</p:column>
                        <p:column>Assumed name</p:column>
                        <p:column>Place</p:column>
                        <p:column>Id</p:column>
                        <p:column>Name</p:column>
                        <p:column>Main color</p:column>
                        <p:column>Size</p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </f:facet>
                <ui:repeat value="#{oneCtrl.stocktakingList}" var="stocktaking">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column rowspan="4">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{stocktaking.ok}" disabled="#{stocktaking.ok}" valueChangeListener="#{oneCtrl.updateStocktaking(stocktaking)}">
                                <p:ajax update=":#{p:component('stocktakingTable')}"/>
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column rowspan="4" style="font-weight: #{stocktaking.ok ? 'normal' : 'bold'}">#{stocktaking.assumedId}</p:column>
                        <p:column rowspan="4" style="font-weight: #{stocktaking.ok ? 'normal' : 'bold'}">#{stocktaking.assumedName}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="font-style: italic">Real Stocktaking</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.realId)}">#{stocktaking.realId}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.realName)}">#{stocktaking.realName}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.realColor)}">#{stocktaking.realColor}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.realSize)}">#{stocktaking.realSize}</p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column style="font-style: italic">Calculated stocktaking</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.calculatedId)}">#{stocktaking.calculatedId}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.calculatedName)}">#{stocktaking.calculatedName}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.calculatedColor)}">#{stocktaking.calculatedColor}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.calculatedSize)}">#{baseCtrl.calculatedSize}</p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column style="font-style: italic">Shop web page</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.shopId)}">#{stocktaking.shopId}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.shopName)}">#{stocktaking.shopName}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.shopColor)}">#{stocktaking.shopColor}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.shopSize)}">#{stocktaking.shopSize}</p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column style="font-style: italic">Online shop web page</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.onlineId)}">#{stocktaking.onlineId}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.onlineName)}">#{stocktaking.onlineName}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.onlineColor)}">#{stocktaking.onlineColor}</p:column>
                        <p:column style="color: #{oneCtrl.AssignedColors.get(stocktaking.onlineSize)}">#{stocktaking.onlineSize}</p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="8" styleClass="ui-widget-header"/>
                    </p:row>
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

I’m sorry if I wasn’t clear enough at first :'(